# Aptana Studio 3.0.9: code assist background color

Tags: colors, background, aptana, background-color, code-assist

I have a problem with colors of code assist. It looks like that: http://ciemborowicz.pl/pub/aptana.png (right bottom corner). I tried to change these colors in  General > Appereance > Colors and Fonts, but it doesn't work. How can I change them?

Comment: The colors should match the theme. Did you try changing the theme through the Themes preference page?

Comment: It looks fine with light themes, but it sucks with all dark themes (even with default). I can't figure what color should I set and where.

Comment: My hunch is that the SWT Browser widget is not available on your linux for some reason. Can you open an internal browser in your Studio?(Window -> Show View -> General -> Internal Browser). Also, have you tried this? http://www.tipstank.com/2010/05/23/solve-eclipse-black-pop-up-code-assist-box-in-ubuntu-10-4-lucid/

Answer (score 2):

Click

```
Window -> Pereferences -> (+)Aptana Studio -> Themes
```

Select the theme:

```
Aptana Studio 2.x
```

Click

```
Apply -> OK
```

Restart Aptana and you should be good to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

> Pereferences >> Aptana Studio >> Themes

and check the Checkbox:

> Enable Invasive Themes

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, the cause is our desktop environment theme. The only solutions I've found so far are:

1. use a light theme in Aptana
2. use a gtk2 theme in Gnome or Lxde

I didn't try it on xfce. I'm trying to find another solution.